# %d format: a number is required, not STR

Tags: python, mysql

When I used python to bulk insert data into mysql, even though I used '%s' to format each word, I still got an error: "%d format: a number is required, not STR".

Code:

```
# SQL 插入语句
sql = ("INSERT INTO sina(topic_info, read_num, top_hot,"
       " create_time, status)"
       " VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' )"
# 一个tuple或者list
T = ( ('易起鏖战 巅峰之战', 133, 4, '2018-8-31:15', '1'),
      ('向往的美食', 123, 2, '2018-8-31:15', '1'),
      ('发际线男孩表情包', 1223, 1, '2018-8-31:15', '1'),
      ('天坑鹰猎开播', 131, 3, '2018-8-31:15', '1'),
      ('如懿传', 121, 5, '2018-8-31:15', '1') )
try:
    # 执行sql语句
    cursor.executemany(sql, T)
    # 提交到数据库执行
    db.commit()
except:
    # 如果发生错误则回滚
    db.rollback()


# database details
| Field       | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+ 
| topfo       | char(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| rm          | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| tot         | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| creme       | char(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| st*us       | char(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       –
```

Comment: show what code you are trying here

Comment: # SQL 插入语句
sql = "INSERT INTO sina(topic_info, read_num, top_hot, create_time, status) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' )"
# 一个tuple或者list
T = (
    ('易起鏖战  巅峰之战', 133, 4, '2018-8-31:15', '1'),
    ('向往的美食', 123, 2, '2018-8-31:15', '1'),
    ('发际线男孩表情包', 1223, 1, '2018-8-31:15', '1'),
    ('天坑鹰猎开播', 131, 3, '2018-8-31:15', '1'),
    ('如懿传', 121, 5, '2018-8-31:15', '1')
)
try:
    # 执行sql语句
    cursor.executemany(sql, T)
    # 提交到数据库执行
    db.commit()
except:
    # 如果发生错误则回滚
    db.rollback()

Comment: MySQL has tables with predefined colomns. Are you sure, you are not inserting a string into a number data colomn.

Comment: It is okay to use %d for single-line inserts, but it is also okay to use %s

For example: "SQL = "INSERT INTO s*a(top*fo, re*m, to*ot, cre*ime,s*us) \

VALUES ('%s', '%d', '%d', '%s', '%s')" % \

"(' if I say ', 121, 5, '2018-8-31:15', '1')

Comment: | Field       | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| top*fo  | char(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| r*m    | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| to*t     | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cre*me | char(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| st*us      | char(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |

Comment: Please use backticks (`) to quote code.  Otherwise the underscores are interpreted as italics markers etc.

Comment: Please give me an example for bulk insert

Comment: No bulk insert possible in comments.  You should edit your original question, there bulk inserts are done by indenting each line with four spaces (you can write or copy/paste your stuff, then select it and press Ctrl-K).  You may lack the ability to edit your question until you have some more reputation, though.

Comment: Shouldn't it be VALUES ('%s', '%d', '%d', '%s', '%s' ) ??? as shown in the database details.

Comment: @NoorJafri This is all string formatting, done before the SQL call.  And though OP gives the error with an ending `STR` (not `str` as in my trials), the error message looks very much like it was coming from the string formatting alone.  And `"%s" % 42` works just fine and gives the same result as `"%d" % 42` (i. e. `"42"`).

Comment: Yes, I used to use %d to format an integer, but this is an error, so try %s formatting, same error

Comment: @AllenPeng I guess you are looking at the wrong spot.  You could double-check the error message and examine the stack trace, compare the line numbers again, etc.  If you are just using `%s` in your format strings, the complaint about an unmatched `%d` is not possibly coming from there.

Comment: that is the "str"

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by reunderstanding the error: "the right syntax to use near 'easy to fight' peak war ', '133', '4', '2018-8-31:15', '1')", because this %s cannot be enclosed in quotation marks for bulk insertion, but it is ok for single insertion.